# Jquery Math with .return

Tags: javascript, jquery, return

```
var john= 5

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#he').append("<h1>" + $(john + 4).return + "</h1>")
})
```

I'm trying to get it to come out to nine, but it comes out undefined. How to fix? Yes, I do realize I could just append a "9", but I'm trying to learn how to do very basic math with Jquery, could you show me how to do it through the function?

Comment: Don t wrap the expression in jQuery - it's not a selector.

Answer (score 3):

```
var john = 5;
$('#he').append('<h1>' + (john + 4) + '</h1>');
```

Answer (score 2):

Well, you could use something like

```
var john= 5

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#he').append("<h1>" + (john + 4) + "</h1>")
})
```

Answer (score 1):

Just change the code to this,

```js
var john= 5

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#he').append("<h1>" + (john + 4) + "</h1>")
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="he"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here you go with one more solution using `ES6`

```js
var john = 5;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#he').append(`<h1>${john + 4}</h1>`);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="he"></div>
```

Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

As the other answers demonstrate, it is for the most part unnecessary to use a return property to display the result of a simple math operation which will evaluate and yield an expression that can be displayed.  Nonetheless, assuming a div element with an id of "he", there are a couple of approaches where one could utilize a return property.  One could specifically use that property of the [event object](https://api.jquery.com/event.result/) whose value is:

> The last value returned by an event handler that was triggered by this
>   event, unless the value was undefined.

One could incorporate this property, as follows:

```js
var john = 5;

$(document).ready(function(){

    $( "button" ).click(function( event ) {
      return john + 4;
    });

    $( "button" ).click(function( event ) {
      $( "#he" ).append( "<h1>" + event.result + "</h1>");
    });
    
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>john + 4 equals?</p>
<button>Display Result</button>
<div id="he"></div>
```

Another interesting thing you can do involves assigning such a property to an element and then use it for the text value for a pair of open and close h1 tags, as follows:

```
var john = 5;

$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#he").prop("return", john + 4);
    $("#he").append("<h1>" + $("#he").prop("return") + "</h1>");

});
```

see [live code](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/JyzYQP)